# How to differentiate between two similar fields in Linq Join tables

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, linq-to-objects

How to differentiate between two select new fields e.g. Description

c.Description and lt.Description

```
    DataTable lDt = new DataTable();
    try
    {

        lDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AreaTypeID", typeof(Int32)));
        lDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CategoryRef", typeof(Int32)));
        lDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(String)));
        lDt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CatDescription", typeof(String)));

        EzEagleDBDataContext lDc = new EzEagleDBDataContext();
        var lAreaType = (from lt in lDc.tbl_AreaTypes
                            join c in lDc.tbl_AreaCategories on lt.CategoryRef equals c.CategoryID
                            where lt.AreaTypeID== pTypeId
                            select new { lt.AreaTypeID, lt.Description, lt.CategoryRef, c.Description }).ToArray();

        for (int j = 0; j< lAreaType.Count; j++)
        {
            DataRow dr = lDt.NewRow();
            dr["AreaTypeID"] = lAreaType[j].LandmarkTypeID;
            dr["CategoryRef"] = lAreaType[j].CategoryRef;
            dr["Description"] = lAreaType[j].Description;
            dr["CatDescription"] = lAreaType[j].;
            lDt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give them an explicit name when selecting:

```
select new { lt.AreaTypeID, LtDescr = lt.Description, lt.CategoryRef, CDescr = c.Description }
```

And then:

```
        dr["Description"] = lAreaType[j].LtDescr;
        dr["CatDescription"] = lAreaType[j].CDescr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
select new { lt.AreaTypeID, lt.Description, lt.CategoryRef, c.Description }
```

To:

```
select new { AreaTypeID = lt.AreaTypeID,
      LtDescription = lt.Description,
      CategoryRef = lt.CategoryRef,
      CatDescription = c.Description }
```

That will give each property in the anonymous type a different explicit name rather than simply relying on the existing name. You can then access them later using:

```
dr["Description"] = lAreaType[j].LtDescription;
dr["CatDescription"] = lAreaType[j].CatDescription;
```